# Typescript: how to import non .ts files as raw string

Tags: typescript, module

[This discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6615#issuecomment-228436645) suggests that in `typescript 2`, it is possible to import an external, non `css` file as a string to be used in my class.

I'm trying to take advantage of this to import HTML into my typescript component so that my application will make one HTTP request fetching the component & its HTML template instead of two separate requests. I've tried:

**typings.d.ts**

```
declare module "*!text" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import htmlTemplate from './app.component.html!text';
...
constructor(){console.log(htmlTemplate)}
```

The typescript compiler raises no error. However, when I run the application, it crashes after requesting `http://localhost/text` and getting a `404` not found`

I've also tried:
**typings.d.ts**

```
declare module "*.html" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import htmlTemplate from './app.component.html';
...
constructor(){console.log(htmlTemplate)}
```

Again no error is raised during compilation but the app requests `http://localhost/app.component.html.js` and crashes after receiving a `404 not found` response.

The template is in `app.component.html`, in the same folder as the `.ts` file. I'm running `typescript 2.0.2`.  How can I import my `.html` templates and `.css` stylesheets as strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I did it, for my `Angular 2 rc.6` application

**1** Install `typescript 2` if you haven't already. Set it as the compiler

```
npm install typescript@2.0.2
```

**2** Set module to `system` in **tsconfig.json**

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    ...
}
```

**3** This broke the app. To fix, [edit every component](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6053#issuecomment-214163297) to use system modules; replace...

```
@Component({
    module: moduleId,
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
```

with...

```
@Component({
    module: __moduleName,
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
```

**4** This will raise errors in typescript because `__moduleName` is unknown. To get rid of it, create a custom definition file (`.d.ts`) in the same directory as your bootstrap file.

**custom.typings.d.ts**

```
/** So typescript recognizes this variable wherever we use it */
declare var __moduleName: string;

/** Will be needed later to import files as text without raising errors */
declare module "*!text"
```

**5** Add a reference to the typed definitions in your bootstrap file so typescript sees them when parsing your code: **main.ts**

```
///<reference path="./custom.typings.d.ts"/>
```

**6** Make sure the app still runs. Next, [install systemjs-plugin-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systemjs-plugin-text):

```
npm install systemjs-plugin-text@0.0.9
```

**7** Set the new plugin as a map in **systemjs.config.js**

```
System.config({
    map:{
        'app':        'app',
        '@angular':   'node_modules/@angular',
        //'text' map is used to import files as raw strings
        text:         'node_modules/systemjs-plugin-text/text.js'
    }
});
```

**8** Now we're all set to import files as strings

```
// this line should raise no error if steps 4 & 5 were completed correctly
import htmlTemplate from './app.component.html!text';
console.log(htmlTemplate); //will print the file as a string in console

@Component({
    moduleId: __moduleName,
    template: htmlTemplate, //success!!
})
```

That's it! Now if you use `systemjs-builder` or a similar bundling tool, the external template will be inlined.